# Taxonomy template using plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have created a wordpress plugin, which creates 2 custom post types and a taxonomy on activation.

The taxonomy name is "product".

I have created a file "taxonomy-product.php"

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Product Archieve
 */

 get_header(); ?>
    <div class="wrap">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <header class="page-header">
                        </header><!-- .page-header -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
//Query for pulling posts
    <?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'product_reviews',
  'post_status' => 'publish',   
 );

$products = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $products->have_posts() ) :
?>

<?php get_footer();
```

This template is included in plugin folder and when the product taxonomy is called, the template shows up, but it throws a fatal error cannot find get_header()

Can some one help me where I am going wrong and how to include a custom taxonomy template using plugin.

Below is the code I used to include custom template in plugin file :

```
 add_filter('template_include', 'set_template');
function set_template( $template ){

       if( is_tax('product'))
        $template = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'templates/taxonomy-product.php';

    return $template;
}
```

This is something similar to including product template in woo commerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the file by path instead of URL, so change

```
$template = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'templates/taxonomy-product.php';
```

to

```
$template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__ ).'templates/taxonomy-product.php';
```